# How can I update multiple array object field in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My mongoose schema is structured this way

```
 {
        "user": "63bue258j43747143hi059d7",
        "images": [
            {
                "image_link": "first-unique-link-http::link-to-image1-63",
                "inStock": false
            },
            {
                "image_link": "second-unique-link-http::link-to-image2-63",
                "inStock": false
            },
            {
                "image_link": "third-unique-link-http::link-to-image3-63",
                "inStock": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user": "9Ef53258j4374714phk625b3",
        "images": [
            {
                "image_link": "anotherFirst-unique-link-http::link-to-image1-9E",
                "inStock": false
            },
            {
                "image_link": "anotherSecond-unique-link-http::link-to-image2-9E",
                "inStock": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to query my mongoose database to update all **inStock** fields that matches the array which conatins the **image_link** to false.

What I want to achieve is something like this query below

```
const imgArr = ['first-unique-link-http::link-to-image1-63', 'third-unique-link-http::link-to-image3-63', 'anotherSecond-unique-link-http::link-to-image2-9E']
const updateStockStatus = await ImageStock.update(
    { "images.image_link": { $in: imgArr } },
    { $set: { 'images.inStock' : true } },
    {multi: true}
 )
```

So after running the query my mongoose schema should look like this

```
{
        "user": "63bue258j43747143hi059d7",
        "images": [
            {
                "image_link": "first-unique-link-http::link-to-image1-63",
                "inStock": true
            },
            {
                "image_link": "second-unique-link-http::link-to-image2-63",
                "inStock": false
            },
            {
                "image_link": "third-unique-link-http::link-to-image3-63",
                "inStock": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user": "9Ef53258j4374714phk625b3",
        "images": [
            {
                "image_link": "anotherFirst-unique-link-http::link-to-image1-9E",
                "inStock": false
            },
            {
                "image_link": "anotherSecond-unique-link-http::link-to-image2-9E",
                "inStock": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) like this:

With `arrayFilters` you are telling mongo: "for the array `images` set only these ones where `elem` matches with predefined one". And `elem` is the objects where `image_link` is in the array.

```js
db.collection.updateMany({},
{
  "$set": {
    "images.$[elem].inStock": true
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.image_link": {
        "$in": imgArr
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v8XDAjvetl0)